# How to create child/sub user under parent user

Tags: multisite, users, user-roles

I've created two custom roles called "Parent" and "Child" and want to have the "Parent" user to create multiple "child" users which are nested under that "Parent".

Comment: I can see multiple questions here, you should ask each question individually "how do I create an admin page", "How can I attach a user to another user with user meta", "How do I create a user in code", "How do I submit a form on a custom admin page", "How do I list all users with a user meta value equal to my current user ID". Each of which is a good question to ask. Asking as you have at the moment though limits the reputation you could get, and greatly reduces the chances of a good answer. Asking each question allows people to answer the parts they know in depth

Comment: Improvised the question which would suffice a single answer. Thanks for pointing out before.

Comment: How do you imagine the handling? Do you have anything tried so far? I reopened the question, but you still need to edit the question to make the goal clear and show us what you have tried and where you failed. "Do this job for me" type questions will not receive answers and likely get closed.

Comment: Thanks but as I've mentioned, I've just created two user roles and want one to be a child of other, literally. Haven't been able to figure out how to even move ahead with it.